# Cleaning a dataset and removing special characters in python

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I am fairly new to all of this so apologies in advance.

I've got a dataset (csv). One column contains strings with whole sentences. These sentences contain missinterpreted utf-8 charactes like `â€™` and emojis like `ðŸ¥³`.

So the dataframe (df) looks kind of like this:

```
           date                                                         text
0   Jul 31 2020       itâ€™s crazy. i hope post-covid we can get it doneðŸ¥³
1   Jul 31 2020       just sayinâ€™ ...
2   Jul 31 2020       nba to hold first games in 'bubble' amid pandemic
```

The goal is to do a sentiment analysis on the texts.

1. Would it be best to remove ALL special characters like `, . ( ) [ ] + | -` to do the sentiment analysis?
2. How do I do that and how do I also remove the missinterpreted utf-8 charactes like `â€™`?

I've tried it myself by using some code I found and changing that to my problem.
This resulted in this piece of code which seems to do absolutly nothing. The charactes like `â€™` are still in the text.

```
spec_chars = ["â€¦","ðŸ¥³"]
for char in spec_chars:
    df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace(char, ' ')
```

I'm a bit lost here.
I appreciate any help!

Comment: I'm just using the df = pd.read_csv('xxx.csv')
Also tried it with df = pd.read_csv('xxx.csv', encoding = 'utf8')
Didn't change anything

Comment: Can you try changing this to `read_csv('xxx.csv', encoding='windows-1252')` -- looks like it's not UTF8.

Comment: @jsmart Then I get this UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 8303: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: This link might help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45749093/in-what-8-bit-character-set-is-0x9d-meaningful -- resolving character encoding can involve a lot of trial and error, sorry there's not a better answer

Comment: chardet might help: https://pypi.org/project/chardet/ (it was mentioned in the SO article in the previous comment)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the character encoding like this.  `x` is one of the sentences in the original post.

```
x = 'itâ€™s crazy. i hope post-covid we can get it doneðŸ¥³'
x.encode('windows-1252').decode('utf8')
```

The result is `'it’s crazy. i hope post-covid we can get it done'`

Comment: Looks promising. How do I apply this to the whole column instead of just one string?

Answer (score 0):

As jsmart stated, use the `.encode` `.decode`. Since the column is a series, you's be using `.str` to access the values of the series as strings and apply the methods.

As far as the text sentiment, look at [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/index.html). And take a look at it's examples of [sentiment analysis](http://www.nltk.org/howto/sentiment.html)

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame([['Jul 31 2020','itâ€™s crazy. i hope post-covid we can get it doneðŸ¥³'],
                   ['Jul 31 2020','just sayinâ€™ ...'],
                   ['Jul 31 2020',"nba to hold first games in 'bubble' amid pandemic"]],
                    columns = ['date','text'])

df['text'] = df['text'].str.encode('windows-1252').str.decode('utf8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's quite helpful for me.

```py
df['clean_text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word.isalnum()])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].