# Unable to import csv file in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, csv, file, import

[I got this error how to resolve this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PB7RV.png)

error
unhandled exception: 'charmap' can't decode byte 0x9d in position 2890. char maps to undefined

I did all the necessary steps to import csv file in mysql workbench but got the above error while selecting utf 8 encoding

this is the log file contents

```
# Copyright (c) 2014, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights 
reserved.
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or 
modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2.0,
# as published by the Free Software Foundation.
#
# This program is also distributed with certain software (including
# but not limited to OpenSSL) that is licensed under separate terms, as
# designated in a particular file or component or in included license
# documentation.  The authors of MySQL hereby grant you an additional
# permission to link the program and your derivative works with the
# separately licensed software that they have included with MySQL.
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,  but
# WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See
# the GNU General Public License, version 2.0, for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation, Inc.,
# 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301 USA

import grt
import os
import traceback

def log_error(msg):    
    tb = traceback.extract_stack(limit=2)
    grt.log_error("%s:%s:%s"%(os.path.basename(tb[-2][0]),tb[-2][2],tb[-2][1]), msg)

def log_warning(msg):
    tb = traceback.extract_stack(limit=2)
    grt.log_warning("%s:%s:%s"%(os.path.basename(tb[-2][0]),tb[-2][2],tb[-2][1]), msg)

def log_info(msg):
    tb = traceback.extract_stack(limit=2)
    grt.log_info("%s:%s:%s"%(os.path.basename(tb[-2][0]),tb[-2][2],tb[-2][1]), msg)

def log_debug(msg):
    tb = traceback.extract_stack(limit=2)
    grt.log_debug("%s:%s:%s"%(os.path.basename(tb[-2][0]),tb[-2][2],tb[-2][1]), msg)

def log_debug2(msg):
    tb = traceback.extract_stack(limit=2)
    grt.log_debug2("%s:%s:%s"%(os.path.basename(tb[-2][0]),tb[-2][2],tb[-2][1]), msg)

def log_debug3(msg):
    tb = traceback.extract_stack(limit=2)
    grt.log_debug3("%s:%s:%s"%(os.path.basename(tb[-2][0]),tb[-2][2],tb[-2][1]), msg)
```

Comment: I did the thing ...excel file ->save as->csvfile->tools->web options->encoding utf 8 and then clicked okay...the file is encoded with utf 8 encoding but the error persists

Comment: It's possible your csv file has junk in it.  You may need to remove the junk before importing it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45749093/in-what-8-bit-character-set-is-0x9d-meaningful

Comment: how to remove junk ...but the thing is the same error appears for all files... exactly the same error comes ...then I guess there is nothing with the file rather with the workbench itself ..i saw the exceptions file of workbench where only one exception was handled classnotfound exception and all other exceptions are not handled. I think the issue is here ...

Comment: The error message is asking you to "check the log for mode details". Did you check it? What did you see? Please add those details also with the question. 
If you don't know where to find log files, this article may help you: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-configuring-files.html

Comment: I have included the log file please see and tell now what to do?

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you're asking, but I've found it easier to just convert the csv to SQL insert statement using this plug-in https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint/ Btw the plugin can also validate the csv file to see if there are any irregularities (aka junk) in the data

Comment: I got so many errors mainly due to different data types in excel and I want to change the data type. I searched the web to change the data type in excel 2016 but the way given by others doesn't work for me. It was written go to fields tab in properties group and change the data type. Now I can't see any properties group in my excel.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found a solution, and maybe this will help. Opening the csv file on notepad, you can see what the ASCII used. Mine was UTF8 BOM, and just changing it to UTF8 solved the problem (if you don't know how, just create a new text file and paste the text in, it works the same, as long as you don't use weird german caracters it should be fine). It's actually a pretty old problem, having more than 2 years that it exists, Oracle just doesn't care about it aparently.

Answer (score 0):

I found another "undocumented anomaly" for this issue. It really was as simple as changing the File extension to ".csv" (lowercase). The import wizard did not like ".CSV" (uppercase).